# How to share Guest's internet on VirtualBox

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have posted my problem almost on every forum and yet couldn't find someone to help me, usually with no respond at all.
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Windows 7 Installed as a Virtual Machine, the only way for me to access the Internet is using a WiMax USB Modem which is not available for Linux, I managed to install it on Windows and get it to work but I don't know how to share that connection with Ubuntu.
Could someone shows me an easy way to do that or provide me a step by step guide, I'm no expert so I don't know much about networking, please help me Thanks!

Comment: You can't share an internet connection **from** a VM guest **to** a VM host.

Comment: 'I managed to install it on Windows': did you mean on a different computer or the Virtual Machine? Since I don't think the 2nd option is possible if you do not have the Linux driver, I am assuming you meant you did it in another computer. Since you will still need the linux driver to be able to share the Internet from another computer to the Linux computer, managing it to run on windows on another computer does not solve your problem in anyway. In fact, without drivers in the host OS, I don't think your guest OS will detect the device, even if you have the drivers for the guest OS.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Windows box with the WiMax USB installed on it to act as a router by installing the routing service on it.

Tutorial:
http://onlize.wordpress.com/2012/08/18/lan-routing-on-windows-server-2008r2-step-by-step/

Use the IP of this Windows box as the gateway for the rest of your LAN and you are done. I would try to get a WiMax router anyway instead of the USB dongle.